# Using Ajax to GET data from Rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get an instance of a modal (in JSON format) by using Ajax when a form is submitted. Currently, on the alert, it outputs nothing, blank.

`alert('<%=  @modal_data.to_json.html_safe %>');` outputs JSON data, but `alert(data);` called through Ajax does not output anything.

Controller

```
class ModalController < ApplicationController
  def modal_index
    @modal_data = Modal.where(:var => params[:attr1])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: @modal_data}
    end
  end
end
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my_form').on("submit", function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "/modal/modal_index",
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: First, make sure you provide params[:attr1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work with JSON you need to set the content type to `application/json`.

if your `$.ajax` call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my_form').on("submit", function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json",      
      url: "/modal/modal_index",
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Also, it doesn't seem you provided the param needed to find the model (attr1).

Keep your controllers standard, pass `id` or `item_id` to get in order to get the object you need.

Comment: Woops, yea I forgot the param... after that it worked. Also, I tried using `contentType: "application/json"`, but that returned an html page instead of a json object. `dataType: "json"` seemed to work.